# What error is my IDE reporting with these CSS snippets?

Tags: css

I was wondering what these errors means. How I can fix them?

First error:

[image: this is the first error]

Second error:

[image: this is the second one]

Comment: Its the `[auto-fit]` remove that or put it properly. To test it out you can comment it and could check others

Comment: You have malformed css, that's not how to implement [`auto-fit`](https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/)

Comment: please paste code as text, not images. you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72103709/edit) your question to fix that.

Comment: I mostly agree with that ethos @Esther, though I think in this case the OP is wanting readers to see the subtle red-wavy underlines, which indicates the IDE is complaining. That cannot be done in text-only representations.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer (-ms-grid-columns) doesn't support auto-fit, minmax, repeat or fit-content. Remove support for internet explorer or build a fallback not based on css grid

Check the compatibility here: https://docs.w3cub.com/css/-ms-grid-columns